# boost program options name for values

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

my goal is to create a program which can handle arguments like this:

`myProgram -i my_int=20 -s my_string=foo -f my_float=3.1415`

**Progress**

my current programm can be executed like this:

`myProgram -i 10 12 2 -s foobar anotherstring -f 3.1425 1.5`

*Notice: no names for the values*

 *Ignore the multiple values*

I've did this with boost program_options:

```
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("float,f", po::value< std::vector<float> >()->multitoken(), "add a float to the map")
    ("int,i", po::value< std::vector<int> >()->multitoken(),"add a int to the map")
    ("string,s", po::value< std::vector<std::string> >()->multitoken(),"add a string to the map")
    ;
```

**What i've tried**

i have tried to give `po::value` this type:

`std::pair<std::string, std::vector<float> >`

but that gives me a complie error

So my question is:

> is it possible to handle program arguments like `-s my_string=str` with the boost library or not?

Comment: Did you try something like `-s "my_string=str"`?

Comment: @Jepessen well then i would need to split the `"my_string=str"` into `my_string` and `str`. Possible, but i am hoping for a better and cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

First off, this grammar strikes me as more involved and you could consider writing a grammar for it.

> This lets you be more flexible adding logic/constraints and also parsing into the AST types you envisioned more directly. For an example of this see this answer:
>
> - [parsing command-line options with sequence containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992776/parsing-command-line-options-with-sequence-containers/26994169)

I found a relatively straightforward way in case you can change the provisional datatype to `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T> >` instead.

Since conversions happen using `lexical_cast<>` you can read any value type that is input-streamable. Let's make `std::pair` input streamable:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename V> static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::pair<std::string, V>& into) {
        char ch;
        while (is >> ch && ch!='=') into.first += ch;
        return is >> into.second;
    }
}
```

Now, you can just make the descriptions:

```
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("float,f",  po::value<Floats>()->multitoken(),  "add a float to the map")
    ("int,i",    po::value<Ints>()->multitoken(),    "add a int to the map")
    ("string,s", po::value<Strings>()->multitoken(), "add a string to the map")
    ;
```

Lets parse your sample command line

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc, po::command_line_style::default_style), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

And print the results of the parse:

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc, po::command_line_style::default_style), vm);
po::notify(vm);

std::cout << "Floats:";    for (auto p : vm["float"].as<Floats>())   std::cout << " ['" << p.first << "' -> " << p.second << "]";
std::cout << "\nInts:";    for (auto p : vm["int"].as<Ints>())       std::cout << " ['" << p.first << "' -> " << p.second << "]";
std::cout << "\nStrings:"; for (auto p : vm["string"].as<Strings>()) std::cout << " ['" << p.first << "' -> " << p.second << "]";
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc22ea12a1830364)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/cmdline.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

using Floats  = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>>;
using Ints    = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>;
using Strings = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;

namespace std {
    template <typename V> static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::pair<std::string, V>& into) {
        char ch;
        while (is >> ch && ch!='=') into.first += ch;
        return is >> into.second;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");

    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("float,f",  po::value<Floats>()->multitoken(),  "add a float to the map")
        ("int,i",    po::value<Ints>()->multitoken(),    "add a int to the map")
        ("string,s", po::value<Strings>()->multitoken(), "add a string to the map")
        ;


    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc, po::command_line_style::default_style), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    std::cout << "Floats:";    for (auto p : vm["float"].as<Floats>())   std::cout << " ['" << p.first << "' -> " << p.second << "]";
    std::cout << "\nInts:";    for (auto p : vm["int"].as<Ints>())       std::cout << " ['" << p.first << "' -> " << p.second << "]";
    std::cout << "\nStrings:"; for (auto p : vm["string"].as<Strings>()) std::cout << " ['" << p.first << "' -> " << p.second << "]";
}
```

Prints:

```
Floats: ['my_float' -> 3.1415]
Ints: ['my_int' -> 20]
Strings: ['my_string' -> foo]
```

Comment: looks very nice... i will try it today :)